# Gsutil cp -z returnsCommandException: Inadequate temp space available to compress

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I keep getting this error when I try to gzip and upload files to GS although I have a lot of free space available. Why is that?
I'm using gsutil version 3.16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

gsutil compresses files in the system's default temp directory (mine is /tmp on ubuntu) and depending on your partitions this can result to failures on large files. It would be better if this could be a parameter within the .boto file rather than using the system-dependent one. You can overcome this by setting your system TMPDIR environment variable before running gsutil

`export TMPDIR=/home/repldba/tempfiles/`

Answer (score 1):

Temp file generation in gsutil is using the python tempfile module, which can be configured as follows:

> tempfile.tempdir When set to a value other than None, this variable
>   defines the default value for the dir argument to all the functions
>   defined in this module.
>
> If tempdir is unset or None at any call to any of the above functions,
>   Python searches a standard list of directories and sets tempdir to the
>   first one which the calling user can create files in. The list is:
>
> The directory named by the TMPDIR environment variable. The directory
>   named by the TEMP environment variable. The directory named by the TMP
>   environment variable. A platform-specific location: On RiscOS, the
>   directory named by the Wimp$ScrapDir environment variable. On Windows,
>   the directories C:\TEMP, C:\TMP, \TEMP, and \TMP, in that order. On
>   all other platforms, the directories /tmp, /var/tmp, and /usr/tmp, in
>   that order. As a last resort, the current working directory.